# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 802200000

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

When I use jdbc to query data from oracle database,
java code like this:

```
ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(apiSql);
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(param);
String sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, paramSource);
List<SqlParameter> declaredParameters = NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(parsedSql, paramSource);
PreparedStatementCreatorFactory creatorFactory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sqlToUse, declaredParameters);
Object[] params = NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, paramSource, null);
PreparedStatementCreator creator = creatorFactory.newPreparedStatementCreator(params);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = creator.createPreparedStatement(conn);

if(batchCount > maxBatchCount || batchCount == 0){
    batchCount = (int)maxBatchCount;
}
preparedStatement.setFetchSize(batchCount);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

I set the fetchSize here.When the fetchSize is 10,the execution is normal.When the fetchSize is 100,000,an error occurs.Here is the error message:

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Error
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.handleConnectionException(DruidDataSource.java:1770)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.handleException(DruidPooledConnection.java:133)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledStatement.checkException(DruidPooledStatement.java:82)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:240)
at com.eternalinfo.alioth.openapi.service.DsApiInfoService.getApiData(DsApiInfoService.java:444)
at com.eternalinfo.alioth.openapi.service.DsApiInfoService.queryForList(DsApiInfoService.java:398)
at com.eternalinfo.alioth.openapi.service.DsApiInfoService.queryForList(DsApiInfoService.java:519)
at com.eternalinfo.alioth.openapi.service.DsApiInfoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b418e4c.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 802200000
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CNumberAccessor.java:201)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:945)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:865)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXD(T4C8Oall.java:790)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:403)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:227)
... 117 more
```

enviroments:
jdk8
ojdbc-11.2.0.4
oracle 10,11,12

I execute a simple full query sql statement with 89 fields. I know that it's possible to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when carring too many arguments in bulk inserts,but I never seen it in queries.

There's nothing on that so far,does anyone know?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the complete error message as text (not as an image).

Comment: Also, please include the *whole* of the code related to this and the *whole* of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the fetch size to 100,000 you're telling the driver to fetch that many rows in one single roundtrip. That means the driver has to allocate enough space in heap to store all these rows before it can start processing them. And in the end it looks like the buffers are being corrupted anyway, hence this error.

This fetch size is much higher than any reasonable number typically used. The default is 10 which may be too small. It's hard to tell what a reasonable number should be in this case without knowing the shape of the row but the rule of thumb is "don't go any higher than 1,000". Past that you'll be in the red zone for sure.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I'm thinking the same thing, I'd like to find a reasonable formula for how to set the correct fetchSize. Maybe it's the number of columns,the amount of data in single row,or cache space,etc. Can these possible factors be put together in a regular way to help me know which fetchSize should be set correctly any time I use it.

Comment: It could be something like f = m / (r+20) where f is your fetch size, m the memory you're willing to allocate for each statement and r is the max row size of RAW data in bytes (20 bytes extra for row metadata)